# How would Mirko Vosk, Mind Drinker's triggered ability work with the Strionic Resonator?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How would [Mirko Vosk, Mind Drinker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirko%20Vosk%2c%20Mind%20Drinker%5d)'s triggered ability work with the [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d)?

My interpretation is that the ability would trigger twice, but only on the original player that took the combat damage.  It could not be copied to a second opponent.  Does anyone have any additional info?

Comment: Re "*the ability would trigger twice*", It only triggers once whenever Mirko Voskdeals combat damage. Copying a triggered ability copies the triggered ability, it doesn't cause the event that triggered the ability to occur twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The copies will always affect the same player as the original ability.**

[Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d) would indeed copy Voks's ability because it's a triggered ability. It allows you to change the *targets* of the copied ability, but [Mirko Vosk, Mind Drinker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirko%20Vosk%2c%20Mind%20Drinker%5d)'s ability does not contain the word "target", so you can't change anything about the copy.

> 706.10. To copy a spell, activated ability, or triggered ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; a copy of a spell isn’t cast and a copy of an activated ability isn’t activated. A copy of a spell or ability copies both the characteristics of the spell or ability and all decisions made for it, including modes, targets, the value of X, and additional or alternative costs. [..]